# what is $W^{-1,2}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, sobolev-spaces

I have been reading about the weak Poincare lemma in the book "Linear and Nonlinear Functional Analysis with Applications" by P.G. Ciarlet.

Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected domain in $\mathbb R^n$. 
I was wondering what the notation $H^{-1}(\Omega,\mathbb R^n)$ means.
Earlier he defined $H^k:=W^{k,2}$, where $W^{k,p}$ denotes the Sobolev spaces.
The theorem goes as follows:

> **Weak Poincare Lemma:**
>   Let there be given a vector field $h\in H^{-1}(\Omega,\mathbb R^n)$ satisfying 
>   $$\mathbf{curl}\,\,h=0\quad\text{in}\,\, H^{-2}(\Omega)$$ 
>   Then there exists $p\in L^2(\Omega)$ such that 
>   $$\mathbf{grad}\,\, p=h\quad\text{in}\,\, H^{-1}(\Omega)$$

To me it seems to be defined as follows:

> $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega,\mathbb R^n)$ if there exists $\tilde f\in W^{1,2}(\Omega,\mathbb R^n)$ such that $D\tilde f=f$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H^{-1}(\Omega )$ is the dual space of $H^1(\Omega )$. In other word, $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega )$ if $$\sup_{\substack{\|\varphi \|\leq 1\\ \varphi \in H^1(\Omega )}}\left|\int_\Omega f\varphi \right|<\infty $$